# OSMF AS3/FlashCS5 Error: Type was not found [...]: StageVideoEvent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, osmf

I am playing around with OSMF and have a problem running even a super simple example.

I am running Flash CS5 on Win7 in VirtualBox on Arch Linux (just saying because I thought that this may have something to do with the underlying stuff). Also I am using OSMF 1.6 Sprint 1.

Anyways I am trying to run this simple example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import org.osmf.containers.MediaContainer;
    import org.osmf.elements.VideoElement;
    import org.osmf.media.DefaultMediaFactory;
    import org.osmf.media.MediaElement;
    import org.osmf.media.MediaPlayer;
    import org.osmf.media.URLResource;

    public class OPlayer extends Sprite {
        public function OPlayer() {
            var filePath:String = "testvid.flv";        
            var resource:URLResource = new URLResource(filePath);       
            var mediaFactory:DefaultMediaFactory = new DefaultMediaFactory();
            var mediaElement:MediaElement = mediaFactory.createMediaElement(resource);
            var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mediaElement);
            var mediaContainer:MediaContainer = new MediaContainer();
            mediaContainer.addMediaElement(mediaElement);
            addChild(mediaContainer);
        }
    }
```

}

And unfortunately I keep getting the following compile error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: StageVideoEvent.
```

Comment: Ok I just tried to edit the file in Flash directly and it seems that there is not flash.events.StageVideoEvent in the classpath. How come? I am using AS3 and it seems like it should be there: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageVideoEvent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StageVideo was only officially released last week, your version probably hasen't been updated with the new API's.

This PDF has info on using it with Flex: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer10_2_p1_releasenotes.pdf

I see you are using Flash CS5, you'll need a playerglobal.swc for that, you could try the Flex one, but I don't think it'll work. Look for a Flash CS5 specific one.

**UPDATE**

I did a quick search and it doesn't look like it is available for Flash Professional CS5 yet, just through the Flex compiler.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have no idea why OSMF is already using it then. I will try 1.5 for now. Thanks for the answer, I was a bit baffled, although i thought that I could fix this by going up a version in flash. Doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it to work quite well using FlashDevelop 4 alpha release http://www.flashdevelop.org/downloads/builds/FlashDevelop-4.0.0-R1747.exe alongside the flex sdk http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero

One thing I have found is that it seems the StageVideoAvailabilityEvent isn't implemented, although I may be wrong about that?

Am getting

[Fault] exception, information=VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.events::StageVideoAvailabilityEvent could not be found.

When using it and I found the following comment on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html

> The "released" version of the
>   reference at
>   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html
>   also contains StageVideo information,
>   but the released version is slightly
>   different -- notably, the
>   StageVideoAvailabilityEvent is not yet
>   supported.

Answer (score 1):

Flex 4.5.1.21328 playerglobal.swc , just download it, you will get it. i met the same problem, now i got it